# How to call oracle procedure from spring data or hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How to call oracle predefined stored procedure which is not associated to any specific entity class.

This stored procedure does not return anything. 
Can this be done from spring  data jpa or hibernate. If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way could be as using `JDBC connection` like following

```
connection().prepareCall("{call storedProcedureName()}").execute()
```

It also can be done from `hibernate sessionFactory connection`

```
(sessionFactory.currentSession as SessionImpl).connection().prepareCall("{call storedProcedureName()}").execute()
```

detail code for spring-web-hibernate

```
https://gist.github.com/lynas/20d61e9b4e74155276a141a7f156bfe6
```

Answer (score 0):

`hibernate-jpa` exposes a `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation which you can use:

```
@Table(name = "TableName")
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "proc_name",
    procedureName = "proc_name",
    resultClasses = {ResultDTO.class},
    parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = BigInteger.class, name = "param")
    }
)
public class ResultDTO { ... }
```

You do have to annotate it as a table and entity so I always just mark it against the table I'm using as the root of my proc.